# PING Remote Desktop Client using batch

Tags: command-line, remote-desktop, ping

I want to create batch file to ping my PC (RDP Client) from my workstation in the office (RDP Host)
but my PC IP is changing each connection (because of using VPN)

so I want to combine these two commands I found on the internet on my batch file

```bat
netstat -n | find ":3389" | find "ESTABLISHED"
```

Which result:

> ***TCP    yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:3389      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57893    ESTABLISHED***
> And move the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx value (my PC IP) to below command

```
ping -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>nul"
```

So my ping result would be something like this:

```bat
Thu 11/12/2020 15:42:04.69 Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=125
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You will need to loop two `for` to get the desired output, one to get and use the output of the `netstat` command and an additional to compose the `ping` command:

```ps1
@echo off

title <nul & title ..\%~nx0
%__AppDir__%mode.com concols=82lines=10

%:^0 < :: loop replace flag "-t" in ping.exe cmd :: >
for /f skip^=1tokens^=4delims^=:^  %%i in ('^^^< nul ^^^
%__AppDir__%netstat.exe -n^|%__AppDir__%find.exe ":3389"^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "ESTABLISHED"
')do for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('%__AppDir__%ping.exe -n 1 -4 %%i^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "from"
')do ^<nul ^ <con: "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe" /q /v:on /c "echo= !date! !time! %%~I" && goto %:^0
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[cmd /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[ping /?](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html)**

  [√] **[Find /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Doskey](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)**

  [√] **[Reg Query](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)**

  [√] **[Goto | call `:label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)**

  [√] **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

Answer (score 0):

@It Wasn't Me

sorry for the late reply
but i couldnt make it work
my batch is like this

`echo Testping start
@echo off
ping -n 10 google.com

echo.

ECHO "What to ping next?"
ECHO "0 = Do Nothing"
ECHO "1 = Continue on google"
ECHO "2 = Remote Desktop resource"

SET /p option=Select:
IF %option%==0  ECHO "Goodbye...!"

IF %option%==1 ping -t google.com|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 google.com>nul"

IF %option%==2 ping -t 10.17.100.72|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 10.17.100.72>nul"

TIMEOUT /T 10 EXIT

:LAST
Echo.`

could you help me integrating your code to here?

 this thing is all new for me